# CSS table-layout to specific row

Tags: css, cross-browser, row, css-tables

Okay, on myBB forum's CSS I have some code.
Because it's so big, I will not post here code, but example which should act same as on forum.

At first, when someone post images, max-width renders fine in every browser except in Firefox where max-width is just ignored and large posted images becomes larger than it's parent.

So, because each post is made in table, I decided to apply Firefox fix like this:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Arial, tahoma, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

And this actually works, but it mess some rows which are not displayed as they should be.

Then I was thought that this may work:

```
table tr:nth-child(2) {table-layout: fixed;}
```

So only specific row which contains post content will be affected, but that doesn't work.
Is there a way to apply table-layout: fixed; to only specific row?

```
<tr><td>I want to NOT be affected by table-layout: fixed;</td></tr>
<tr><td>I want to be affected by table-layout: fixed;</td></tr>
<tr><td>I want to NOT be affected by table-layout: fixed;</td></tr>
```

Comment: table is displayed as a whole block and you cannot do this this way. can you set a example online on fiddle, codepen or jsbin, so we see your code in action and see what workaround to propose.  TR are not wrapped in TD, a mistake of yours? i guess

Comment: Check this out: http://www.elite7hackers.us/showthread.php?tid=673&pid=3507#pid3507

Check source code for CSS and HTML. Check in Firefox to see how images being larger that it should.

Comment: Yes my bad with TR TD. I corrected it now.

Comment: Hi, can you set a fiddle or codepen with some code that shows your problem. so, we may be abble to advise you, with a workaround. You understand that the use of table-layout:fixed; can only be applied to table and not a specific tr. unless with some workaround you decide to reset display on tr or other method  to get what you expect..

Comment: still looking for help, can i expect any feedback of yours from my last comment :) ?

Comment: Go here and see the source  elite7hackers.us/showthread.php?tid=673&pid=3507#pid3507.
Everything is in there.